# wxPython Password, TextCtrol(TE_PASSWORD) isn't allowing ID_OK

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

Trying to get a password for an application to process here, but the only way I can get the `ID_OK` and `CANCEL` buttons to display in the frame is to actually make it a dialog.  I have no problem doing this, I actually think it looks nicer, but I can't get the dialog to accept a `TE_PASSWORD` or otherwise hide the characters that are typed.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Please enter your password.','Password Prompt')
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        password = dlg.GetValue()
        msg = "Please enter your password."
        title = 'Request Email Verification'
        Password = password
    dlg.Destroy()
```

If I add a `TE_PASSWORD` into the `dlg =` the `wx.ID_OK` is ignored.  Toughts?

Comment: After digging through the docs I found that I could have just changed `TextEntryDialog` to `PasswordEntryDialog`.  How stupid is that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a wx.Dialog instead. Then you can put a text control on it using the wx.TE_PASSWORD style you mentioned. You can add a button and set its id to wx.ID_OK. Something like the following should work:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class LoginDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Login")

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        userLbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Username:")
        userTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.addWidgets(userLbl, userTxt)

        passLbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Password:")
        passTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        self.addWidgets(passLbl, passTxt)

        okBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        btnSizer.Add(okBtn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        cancelBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        btnSizer.Add(cancelBtn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.mainSizer.Add(btnSizer, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def addWidgets(self, lbl, txt):
        """
        """
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(txt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    dlg = LoginDialog()
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
    app.MainLoop()
```